# Cannot resolve server - DNS problem?

Tags: 14.04, internet, dns

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on an old netbook. I have traveled to a new location and logged onto their internet connection connection over wifi.

Unfortunately, intermittently (sometimes after a minute, sometimes after 10) any call to an web page seems to hang. I can just disconnect from the wifi and reconnect. Web pages are then returned as expected for a few minutes.

I thought it was a DNS issue and following this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558141/ubuntu-12-04-cant-resolve-hostname) I tried

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

and even

```
echo "nameserver vv.xx.yy.zz" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf && echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8" "\nnameserver 8.8.4.4" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

That also seems to work for a few minutes, but then the old problem returns

Can someone please help?

Comment: You shouldn't manually edit/change /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Thanks heynnema. I understand why you say that, but I was following an accepted answer on the forum. Having followed the recommendation my position is no worse but it is not resolved. I'm struggling, and telling me what NOT to do is not as constructive as I would have hoped

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't have more positive ideas to help you fix your problem. Your problem could be a number of things... but the one thing that I did want to relay to you was about not editing that file. I hope that somebody has some ideas to help you fix your problem. Good luck in the future.

Comment: The symptoms are typical of a problem in the new WiFi network you're connected to, probably with some WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and/or TKIP. Some Linux drivers don't like those settings, at all. There are other possible causes too but DNS issues isn't one of them. WiFi disconnecting but otherwise working as expected while connected is not a DNS issue.

Comment: Thanks heynnema and CelticWarrior. I now realise I have explained the problem incorrectly (your responses have help me to focus better) I have changed the question, but for completeness, the Internet connection is not dropping, but a call to a web page does hang. Either disconnecting and reconnecting or entering the above 'echo' command and then calling the page again resolves the issue for a while

Comment: Does the new wireless location use DSL? If so, you'll need to change your MTU... probably to 1492. Report back. Start new comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.